# i can't login to phpmyadmin but i can in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, mariadb

am running a fresh install of xubuntu,i have just installed lamp everything is working only i connot login to phpmyadmin to import my databases, and yet i can login to mysql in terminal.

[image: as you can see i cannot login in php myadmin]

[image: in terminal i do login]

what could be the problem

Comment: See this question and answer: http://superuser.com/questions/1150923/mariadb-root-user/1150939#1150939 . You are using the same package, you run MySQL client under `root`, and since you haven't mentioned anything about re-configuring your roots, it's likely that you also have `unix_socket` for the local root.

Comment: So you add a password for the user `root` and now you can't access to phpMyAdmin, is that correct?

Comment: exactly that is what i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i run this command and it worked

> echo "update user set plugin='' where User='root'; flush privileges;"
>   | mysql -u root -p mysql

and entered my root password.

thanks everyone

Comment: This is the same as logging into mysql via console and typing
update user set plugin="" where User="root";
flush privileges;

Answer (score 1):

Add `-h localhost` to the commandline attempt.  If it fails, then the problem is with "localhost".  You may be connecting via `127.0.0.1` or something else that 'seems' equivalent.

Perhaps the simplest solution is to do (from the commandline tool)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'the same password';
```

Comment: In newer versions, see also `mysql_native_password`.